# How can I restart just one job on Appveyor

Tags: appveyor

One of a very kind volunteers helped to get M2Crypto almost to the shape that it builds on Windows. We use Appveyor CI for testing (I am a Linux guy, so I don't even have an access to a Windows machine), everything works well, when it does, but it is quite unreliable. M2Crypto is using [swig](http://www.swig.org/) and downloading it for every job seems [quite](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mcepl/m2crypto-6gp50/build/job/6wkwa53w5lmt7epx) [unreliable](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mcepl/m2crypto-6gp50/build/1.0.42/job/d08d1ggday5do8pb). Any ideas how to make choco more reliable?

Or, would it be possible to restart just one job (not whole commit), so that when this happens, I could get passing commit with restarting a job?

Thank you for great service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Caching chocolatey packages](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-cache/#caching-chocolatey-packages).

[Restarting a single job in the matrix](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/58) is still not implemented.